# Cant get specific subdoc and a 'root' value in the same call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I can get the specific sub document, but I want to have the email also

```
//The object in the Db looks like this:
{
    _id: some_id,
    email: "an email",
    order: [{
        fakturaId: faktura_id,
        name: "Some name"
        ...
     },...]
}

const salg = await mgUser.find(
    { _id: ObjectId('some_id')},
    {
        order: {
            $elemMatch: { fakturaId: faktura_id }
        }
    }
)
```

I get :

```
 {
        fakturaId: faktura_id,
        name: "Some name"
        ...
 }
```

And would like to have :

```
{
email : "an email",
     {
            fakturaId: faktura_id,
            name: "Some name"
            ...
     }
}
```

Or any kind where I get the email

Comment: try `ObjectId(faktura_id)`

Comment: thanks made en edit, but that's not where it's wrong... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add email to the projection:

```
const salg = await mgUser.find(
    { _id: ObjectId('some_id')},
    {
        email: 1,
        order: {
            $elemMatch: { fakturaId: faktura_id }
        }
    }
)
```